# Stripe - payments in different currencies in different countries

Tags: stripe-payments, integration, payment

I am integrating my service with Stripe for subscription payment processing.
I want the service to be available in different countries. Therefore I would like to offer my subscription in different currencies in different countries.
For example, say my subscription costs 10 USD / month for American users.
What is the best practice with Stripe when it comes to offering the same product in different currencies depending on the user's location? (for example 12 EUR for Germans, 15 GBP for UK etc.).

One thing that comes to my mind is to have a single Stripe product, with multiple prices defined in different currencies, use some 3rd party IP location service to find out where the request comes from and display different pricing options depending on the user location. So I would have the price_ids mapped to countries on the server side, determine the location on the client side and pass it on to the server when fetching available products.
Is this the best practice or is it normally done differently?

Answer (score 3):

Has this been solved?

I'm using Stripe Checkout (checkout system made by Stripe), which picks up prices for my products and CONVERTS them to user's local currency.

The problem, though, is that €99 gets converted to ~$118.02, but I'd like to specify the price for USD myself (would be $119). Can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you're right, it should also just convert the currencies through Stripe itself

Answer (score -1):

Once you have created a Product, you can specify the `currency` when [creating Prices](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/prices-guide#create-prices). The amount will be [converted to your default currency](https://stripe.com/docs/currencies/conversions) if you don't have a bank account in the specified currency.

Comment: I think it will be converted if for example my price is in USD and my account is GBP. I don't mean that though. What I mean is - how can I charge different amounts depending on user's location - so how can I have different prices with different currencies in my offer

Comment: I'd suggest starting at https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/user-location since you're really asking how to detect the user's location. From there you'd just set the amount/currency as you like when creating the payments.

Comment: @taintedzodiac browser geolocation is opt-in, and even if the user does opt-in, they can easily spoof their location with a VPN.

Comment: @JoshNoe naturally. Do you feel that changes anything in regards to how you detect a user's location? (I should also note that this is a side discussion to the original question, which has also changed over time since I answered years ago -- so likely if you're curious you should open a new one!)